# Product of Vector Spaces vs Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following definition from *Linear Algebra Done Right* (Sheldon Axler) what mathematician's normally call the "direct sum?"

[image]

Comment: No and yes. See internal direct sum and external direct sum.

Comment: So, this would be an external direct sum?

Comment: @Jbag1212 Yes, that's correct. Also, [link to the relevant wiki subsection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Internal_and_external_direct_sums)

Comment: @Jbag1212 Another point is that in the case of infinitely many spaces $V_i$ (with $i$ from some infinite indexing set $I$), there is a difference between the (external) direct sum $\bigoplus_{i \in I} V_i$ and the product $\prod_{i \in I} V_i$.

Comment: I think that it is cleaner to use the term "product" as in 3.71 above and to use the term "direct sum" as in Definition 1.40 of Linear Algebra Done Right. Note that in the context of a direct sum, all the subspaces live in a common vector space. Of course, a direct sum of subspaces of a vector space is isomorphic to a product, but that statement does not even make sense unless one keeps the concepts of direct sum and product distinct.